# How can I stop my Samsung NC150+ from thinking it's american and no longer being able to connect to wireless networks set to channel 12 and 13

Tags: wireless, samsung

So a while a go I discovered that the reason why everyone else was able to connect to the wireless except for me (whilst being able to see other networks) was that the wireless  I used to be able to connect to is on channel 13 and my computer only sees up to 11 these days. How would I go about having it listen to 12 and 13 again?

Comment: +1 I had the same problem and had to reconfigure my router to use channel 6 instead. I could not find a solution.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but i solved it by reading this post : http://hmh-ev.dyndns.org/mywiki/wlan
Sorry for my bad English.
I hope this info can be helpful
Thanks 
John..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.